# How to take odd and even line numbers of text from a file and write them to new files?

Tags: c, file

I have a project and it's like this. I need a write some text to a file and this text has several lines.
Then if the line's number is odd, it should be written to odd_linenumber_texts file. And if the line's number is even, it should be written to even_linenumber_texts file.
I searched it on many websites but I only found for codes that separates numbers not line numbers of text.
Actually this is close to what I want to do. How can I make this separate the number of lines by odd/even and write to necessary file.
Here's what I found:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int isEven(const int NUM);
int isPrime(const int NUM);
int main()
{
FILE * fp,
     * fpEven, 
     * fpOdd; 

int num, success;

fp = fopen("data/numbers.txt", "r");
fpEven = fopen("data/even-numbers.txt" , "w");
fpOdd  = fopen("data/odd-numbers.txt"  , "w");

if(fp == NULL || fpEven == NULL || fpOdd == NULL)
{
    printf("Unable to open file.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

while (fscanf(fp, "%d", &num) != -1)
{
    if (isEven(num))
        fprintf(fpEven, "%d\n", num);
    else
        fprintf(fpOdd, "%d\n", num);
}
fclose(fp);
fclose(fpEven);
fclose(fpOdd);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use a for loop for it. The index is your line number. Of course, you can also use this while loop, but then you would need to increment `num` somewhere. Otherwise, you will always read the same line.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```c
int num = 1;

while (fscanf(fp, "%d", &num) != -1)
{
    if (isEven(num))
        fprintf(fpEven, "%d\n", num);
    else
        fprintf(fpOdd, "%d\n", num);

    num++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact you want to write every second line in a different file. No need to test whether the line number is even of odd:

```
...
int even = 0;                        // first line will be odd
while (fscanf(fp, "%d", &num) != -1)
{
    if (even)
        fprintf(fpEven, "%d\n", num);
    else
        fprintf(fpOdd, "%d\n", num);
    even = 1 - even;                  // flip even on each line
}
```

Comment: Nice approach! However, if you use this approach, wouldn't it be simpler to do `bool is_even = true;` on your first line, and on the last line `is_even = !is_even;`? Sure, `true` and `false` are represented as `1` and `0`, but isn't it easier to read?

Comment: @MacOS: When I learned K&R C in the 80's the boolean type did not exist. So when I program in C, I often use int type for boolean values. Dinosaurs are like that...

Answer (score 0):

I rearranged my code, I don't know if it is actually work. I need to do this. Open odd number file and print line 1,line 3, line 5. And oper even number file, print line 2, line 4, line 6.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
int isEven(const int NUM);
int isPrime(const int NUM);
int main() 
{ 
char name[64];
FILE * fp,
     * fpEven, 
     * fpOdd; 

int num, success;
 printf("Dosya ismi: ");
 fgets(name, 64, stdin);
 fp = fopen("data/numbers.txt", "w+");
 fputs("Line 1", fp);
 fputs("Line 2", fp);
 fputs("Line 3", fp);
 fputs("Line 4", fp);
 fputs("Line 5", fp);
 fputs("Line 6", fp);
 fpEven = fopen("data/even-numbers.txt" , "w");
 fpOdd  = fopen("data/odd-numbers.txt"  , "w");

if(fp == NULL || fpEven == NULL || fpOdd == NULL)
{
    printf("Unable to open file.\n");
    exit(-1);
}
 int even = 0;                        
 while (fscanf(fp, "%d", &num) != -1)
 {
 if (even)
    fprintf(fpEven, "%d\n", num);
 else
    fprintf(fpOdd, "%d\n", num);
 even = 1 - even;                   
 }
 fclose(fp);
 fclose(fpEven);
 fclose(fpOdd);
 return 0;
 }
```